# Difference between routed protocol and routing protocol

Tags: routing, protocol

What is the difference between routed protocol and routing protocol?. Clear answers will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps if you ask a clear question (giving some context) you might get a clear answer?

Comment: What does your research tell you? [what is the difference between routed and routing protocols?](https://learningnetwork.cisco.com/thread/56797) seems to have pretty good answers. What is it exactly you don't understand?

Comment: [Difference between Routed and Routing Protocols](http://howdoesinternetwork.com/2012/difference-between-routed-routing-protocols)

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I was about to write an unclear answer.  But then I read the rest of the question.  It doesn't come right out and say that unclear answers would not be highly appreciated, but it's sort of implied.  No sense taking the chance, putting all that work into an unclear answer if you're going to be all fussy like that.

Answer (score 2):

A routed protocol is a protocol that is typically routed or is capable of being routed. IP is a routed protocol.

A routing protocol is a protocol used to maintain routing tables and provide information to support routing. [RIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routing_Information_Protocol) is a routing protocol.

Answer (score 1):

## Routed Protocol

A routed protocol is a protocol by which data can be routed. Routed protocol are IP, AppleTalk, and IPX. In this kind of protocols we require an addressing scheme and subnetting. Addressing scheme will be used to determine the network to which a host belongs and to identifying that host on that particular network. All hosts on an internetwork are using the services of a routed protocol. That means routers, servers, and workstations to. The only two routed protocols that are in use today are IP and IPX but IPX is dropped from Cisco in exams and is not in use much these days. If you are studying routed protocols the best advice is to focus on IP routed protocol.

## Routing protocol

A routing protocol is different and is only used between routers. It makes possible for routers to build and maintain routing tables. There are three classes of routing protocols- 1)distance vector, 2)link state,3)hybrid
OSPF is one of two link state protocols, the other one is IS-IS. EIGRP is the only hybrid protocol but in normal literature you will see that EIGRP is distance vector routing protocol.

Comment: @mahmoudyoussef Wrong one hahah.